# Не могу наследовать класс QNetworkReply

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Всем привет. Второй день бьюсь головой и не могу наследоваться от класса QNetworkReply. Я не знаю что уже я делаю неправильно по этой причине вынужден обратится к вам всем за помощью.

myqnetworkreply.h

```
#ifndef MYQNETWORKREPLY_H
#define MYQNETWORKREPLY_H

#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QObject>
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class MyQNetworkReply : public QNetworkReply
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyQNetworkReply(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~MyQNetworkReply();

    void downloadProgress(qint64 ist, qint64 max);
};
QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // MYQNETWORKREPLY_H
```

myqnetworkreply.cpp

```
#include "myqnetworkreply.h"

QT_USE_NAMESPACE

MyQNetworkReply::MyQNetworkReply(QObject *parent) : QNetworkReply(parent)
{

}

MyQNetworkReply::~MyQNetworkReply()
{

}

void MyQNetworkReply::downloadProgress(qint64 ist, qint64 max)
{
    ist = 0;
    max = 0;
}
```

В QNetworkReply есть функция downloadProgress(), собственно её мне и нужно вытащить.

Получаю вот такую ошибку: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'MyQNetworkReply' replyL = new MyQNetworkReply(this);

Код основного класса

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //myReply = new MyQNetworkReply(this);
    //replyL = new QNetworkReply(this);
    NetworkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    process = new QProcess(this);

    //connect(replyL, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, this, &MainWindow::downloadProgress);

    connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::startDownload);
    connect(NetworkManager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &MainWindow::downloadFinished);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::startDownload()
{
    QUrl url("http://www.eqdrive.com.ua/files/Updates/UpdateEQDriveConfig/UpdaterEQDrive.exe");
    QNetworkRequest downloadRequest;
    downloadRequest.setUrl(url);
    NetworkManager->get(downloadRequest);

    //QNetworkReply *reply = NetworkManager->get(downloadRequest);
    //connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, this, &MainWindow::downloadProgress);
    //connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::readyRead, this, &MainWindow::saveDownloadedFile);
}

void MainWindow::downloadFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    if(reply->error())
    {
        qDebug() << reply->errorString();
    } else {
        QByteArray downloadedFile = reply->readAll();
        QFile *file = new QFile("UpdaterEQDrive.exe");
        if(file->open(QFile::WriteOnly))
        {
            file->write(downloadedFile);
            file->close();
            qDebug("Download Finished");
        }
    }

}

void MainWindow::saveDownloadedFile()
{
    counter++;
    qDebug() << "Save file " << counter;
    //NetworkManager->get(downloadRequest);

}

void MainWindow::downloadProgress(qint64 ist, qint64 max)
{
    ui->progressBar->setRange(0, max);
    ui->progressBar->setValue(ist);
}
```

Comment: `downloadProgress()` — это не функция, это *сигнал*... скорей всего тебе нужно не наследовать, а присоединить его к какому-либо слоту (в зависимости от того, что именно ты пытаешься сделать на самом деле).

Comment: @Fat-Zer да, Вы правы. Это сигнал. в главном классе я пытаюсь работать с QNetworkReply и использовать его сигнал. Но не могу выделить память. В .h файле пишу QNetworkReply *reply; а в .cpp reply = new QNetworkReply(this); и получаю такую ошибку: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'MyQNetworkReply' reply = new MyQNetworkReply(this); попытался наследоваться и всё-равно ничего не выходит

Comment: обычно самостоятельно создавать `QNetworkReply` не имеет смысла — по факту это промис возвращаемый `QNetworkAccessManager`... как пользоваться последним, см. примеры в [доках](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details)... также, что именно ты пытаешься сделать? (см. также [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy))

Comment: @Fat-Zer Мне нужно сделать progressBar. Скачивание я реализовал, а вот progressBar сломался. Я выше добавил код основного класса

Comment: собственно раскоментируй полезные части в `MainWindow::startDownload()` и добавь по аналогии с тем, что уже есть `connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, this, MainWindow::downloadProgress);`... если всё остальное правильно объявлено, то то что ты привёл выглядит сносно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer да. Всё заработало. Раскоментировал 2 первые строки с MainWindow::startDownload() и всё заработало. Аж стыдно, что так тупил. Теперь могу переносить код в основной проект. Спасибо Вам большое :))

Answer (score 1):

Решение проблемы оказалось простой. В функции `MainWindow::startDownload()` нужно раскомментировать 2 строчки кода:

```
QNetworkReply *reply = NetworkManager->get(downloadRequest);
connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, this, &MainWindow::downloadProgress);
```

и `progressBar` заработает как нужно. Спасибо за это Fat-Zer

Comment: Ничего не понял. Каким образом это помогло вам инстанциировать ваш абстрактный класс `MyQNetworkReply`? Каким образом "расскомментирование" посторонних строчек могло исправить совершенно не сязанную с ними ошибку???

Comment: @AnT забудьте за этот класс. У меня всего-лишь не работал progressBar. Мне не нужно было от него наследоваться.

Comment: Ну то есть ваш ответ не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу.